# Classification of texture images containing very high randomness

Tags: image-processing

I like to know what is the best way of classifying texture images that have extreme randomness but contains slight repeated patterns. I know nothing in this area and any link that points to good resources are welcome.

I want to separating two images that contain 8 bit grayscale textures that have visually no image but i suppose algorithms are able to detect similarities and differences.

Comment: Hi, the first thing you might want to do is to look for publications on scholar.google.com (It is helpful to click on "versions", often the paper is freely accessable). The second is, that your question is really vague. It would be nice to see some examplary image.

Comment: Try the LU-transform. It is single-valued and the paper has samples of textures with randomness being classified. http://www.mobvis.org/publications/tavakoli_etal_CIMCV06.pdf

Answer (score 2):

basically you need to extract texture features. Some of the texture features you should try using are
1. GLCM features (matlab implementation : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22187-glcm-texture-features)
2. LBP (local binary pattern) 
3. Gabor features (I have an implementation for this, pls tell me if u want these)
4. Wavelet features

Another excellent source to solution to your problem 
http://academiccommons.columbia.edu/download/fedora_content/download/ac:128294/CONTENT/81.pdf

Comment: i think you have covered most of the standard texture descriptors. which of these are applicable cannot be said unless actually run on the images. btw the Gabor implementation could come in handy for a lot o things. would you consider hosting the code somewhere and linking to this question?

Comment: I have uploaded the gabor features implementation on mathworks filexchange it should be up in a couple of days. Alternately I have hosted it on dropbox and can be downloaded from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28068989/Gabor_Image_Features.rar

Comment: @AruniRC I am just curious to have a look at the images you working on. btw, did the gabor features code work?

Comment: i mentioned including Gabor filters because it usually comes in handy a lot. right now I'm working with ICDAR 2003 Robust Reading images (available on the net). And my code is in C and OpenCV so won't be using any copy/past from Matlab.

Comment: But I can u can implement it in C look at the matlab code. if u happen to implement gabor feature extraction in C pls do let me know.